# Angular 6 IE11 Compatibility

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills

I took all necessary steps in polyfills.ts but still getting this error when run the Angular app on IE

```
 SCRIPT1002: Syntax error   
 vendor.js (463953,1)
```

and this is the line of error :

```
OrbitControls extends three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["EventDispatcher"]
```

polyfills.ts
http://jsfiddle.net/v179oeq3

package.json
http://jsfiddle.net/728gm5b0/

Comment: After doing changes in polyfills file did you run npm install?

Comment: @Krishna yes I did.

Comment: Hi, I juts took one fresh project, Without any polyfills changes it was giving me SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
After just poyfills update and after running npm install --save classlist.js its working in Internet Explorer.
Can you tell me if you have uncommented all files in pollyfills related to IE10 & IE11?

Comment: yes I did uncommented those and npm install packages

Comment: Can you post your polyfills & package.json file. Also clear all cache of IE and Check

Comment: @Krishna post edited with the files, Thanks

Comment: Approach One:-
import "core-js/es7/array"; & import "web-animations-js"; are commented in my project.
delete your node_modules; npm verify cache and then run npm install
Approach Two:-
Can you try upgrading your project to latest angular. I think this bug was there in 6.0 which is later fixed. Just run ng update and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was for Three Js library . seems that I can't use it in IE and once removed worked on IE 11.

Comment: Which library's where they?

Comment: ThreeJs library

Comment: Oh, I thought it were 3 different libraries. Sorry.